# AutomationElement / Context Menus

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation, automationelement

### Description

I am trying to be able to interact with context menus using UI Automation. Basically, I am trying to:

- set focus on an `AutomationElement`
- `SendKeys.SendWait` to send a `SHIFT+F10`
- see what pops up

### What I Am Seeing

What I am seeing is that the `AutomationElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, Condition.TrueCondition)` does not seem to reflect when the context menu is popped, even though UISpy sees it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Example

Here is an example application that I have been running in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/):

```cpp
void Main()
{
  var notepad = FindNotepad();
  Console.WriteLine("Pre-Context: {0}", Descendants(notepad).Count);
  TypeInto(notepad, "(+{F10})");
  Thread.Sleep(1000);

  Console.WriteLine("With Context: {0}", Descendants(notepad).Count);
  TypeInto(notepad, "{ESC}");
  Console.WriteLine("Post-Context: {0}", Descendants(notepad).Count);
}

AutomationElement FindNotepad(string title = "Untitled - Notepad")
{
  var notepadName = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, title);
  return AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, notepadName);
}

void TypeInto(AutomationElement element, string keys)
{
  element.SetFocus();
  SendKeys.SendWait(keys);
}

AutomationElementCollection Descendants(AutomationElement element)
{
  return element.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, Condition.TrueCondition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The context menu that opened on Shift-F10 is actually a child of the root element (desktop) so if you use `Descendants(AutomationElement.RootElement).Count` instead of `Descendants(notepad).Count` you will see the difference.
e.g.

```
Pre-Context: 2019
With Context: 2036
Post-Context: 2019
```